# The result fall into an infinite cycle in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, shopify

Could anyone help me to fix my issue?  I'm a starter in React.js and I just made the component to show the cart results! but for some reason, it falls into an infinite cycle.

Issue screenshot: http://prntscr.com/1w5hbey

you can see the console data with this site URL. Thank you

https://side-cart-react.myshopify.com/products/test2

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import ReactDom from "react-dom"

const LineItem = (props) => {
    return (
    <div className="line-item" data-line="">
      <div className="line-item__header">
        <div className="line-item__title">
          <p>{console.log(props.cart)}</p>
        </div>
        <p className="line-item__price"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

const CartDrawer = () => {

    const [cart, setCart] = useState("");

    const getCart = () => {
        fetch("/cart.js", {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: new Headers({'content-type': 'application/json', 'X-Requested-With':'xmlhttprequest'})
        }).then(res => {
            return res.json();
        }).then(json => {
                setCart(json);
            console.log('state',cart);
        });
    }

    getCart();

    return  <LineItem cart={cart} />;
}

const root = document.getElementById('cart__drawer_items');

ReactDom.render(<CartDrawer />, root);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setCart(json)`, it causes a rerender of your component. On this subsequent render, your function `getCart()` get called again, and thus you trap yourself inside an infinite loop. Instead, you should call `getCart()` within `useEffect` like this:

```js
const CartDrawer = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getCart();
  }, []);

  return  ...;
}
```

This way, it will be called only once. If you want cart to update when some state or props change, you should add those variables into `useEffect` dependency array.

Comment: Could you post full code? thank you

Comment: I am sorry, but no, please refer to React documentation for the details on useEffect hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: I'm facing up the 'useEffect is not defined' issue, this is hook?

Comment: Yes, it's working. thank you